# What is the DataKinds extension of Haskell?

Tags: haskell, types, algebraic-data-types, data-kinds

I am trying to find an explanation of the DataKinds extension that will make sense to me having come from only having read [Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/). Is there a standard source that will make sense to me with what little I've learned?

Edit: For example the [documentation](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.2/html/users_guide/promotion.html) says

> With -XDataKinds, GHC automatically promotes every suitable datatype
>   to be a kind, and its (value) constructors to be type constructors.
>   The following types

and  gives the example

```
data Nat = Ze | Su Nat
```

give rise to the following kinds and type constructors:

```
Nat :: BOX
Ze :: Nat
Su :: Nat -> Nat
```

I am not getting the point. Although I don't understand what `BOX` means, the statements `Ze :: Nat` and `Su :: Nat -> Nat` seem to state what is already normally the case that Ze and Su are normal data constructors exactly as you would expect to see with ghci

```
Prelude> :t Su
Su :: Nat -> Nat
```

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Well let's start with the basics

#### Kinds

Kinds are the types of types*, for example

```
Int :: *
Bool :: *
Maybe :: * -> *
```

Notice that `->` is overloaded to mean "function" at the kind level too. So `*` is the kind of a normal Haskell type.

We can ask GHCi to print the kind of something with `:k`.

#### Data Kinds

Now this is not very useful, since we have no way to make our own kinds! With `DataKinds`, when we write

```
 data Nat = S Nat | Z
```

GHC will promote this to create the corresponding kind `Nat` and

```
 Prelude> :k S
 S :: Nat -> Nat
 Prelude> :k Z
 Z :: Nat
```

So `DataKind`s makes the kind system extensible.

#### Uses

Let's do the prototypical kinds example using GADTs

```
 data Vec :: Nat -> * where
    Nil  :: Vec Z
    Cons :: Int -> Vec n -> Vec (S n)
```

Now we see that our `Vec` type is indexed by length.

That's the basic, 10k foot overview.

* This actually continues, `Values : Types : Kinds : Sorts ...` Some languages (Coq, Agda ..) support this infinite stack of universes, but Haskell lumps everything into one sort.

Comment: Does this mean that the expression `S :: Nat -> Nat` is overloaded in that it can refer to `S` as a data constructor taking an argument of type `Nat` or `S` as a type constructor taking an argument of kind `Nat`? Should your example of `data Vec :: Nat -> *` be instead `data Vec a :: Nat -> *` to reflect that `Vec` takes a type argument?

Comment: @user782220 1. Yes 2. No, I deliberately made `Vec` monomorphic, you could if you wanted to

Comment: What do you mean by `Vec` monomorphic? How does it make sense to speak of `data Vec :: Nat -> *` without any reference to the argument?

Comment: @user782220 `Vec` only works over `Int`s. Read the constructors.. It's exactly the same as `[Int]` + lengths in the types

Comment: Not understanding why it makes sense to omit the `a` I would be equally confused if for example I saw `data Maybe = Nothing | Just a`  instead of `data Maybe a = Nothing | Just a`.

Comment: @user782220 What I have is more like `data MaybeInt = Nothing | Just Int`. I could have but in the extra type parameter but it makes exactly 0 difference to the subject at hand: Kinds.

Comment: But isn't it the case that with `data MaybeInt = Nothing | Just Int` there is only one type `Int`. Since there are multiple types of kind `Nat` wouldn't it make more sense to speak of `data Maybe a = Nothing | Just a` with some syntax to express the constraint that `a` should be a type coming from kind `Nat`. In such a case I still don't see how `data Maybe = Nothing | Just a` would make sense.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43685/discussion-between-jozefg-and-user782220)

Comment: I think the easiest thing to overlook in all of this is that without DataKinds, `S` and `Z` are not types, but just type constructors producing the type `Nat`.  With DataKinds, they're types, whose kind is `Nat`.  The fact that they weren't types before means that previously they couldn't be referred to in type signatures, which is what this is all about.

Comment: @jozefg FWIW, I found your chat comments quite helpful. Thanks for taking the time!

Comment: @Jules, that comment should be an Answer! Typically when I've seen use of  -XDataKinds, it's because something requires the  constructor in a function signature (or conversely, when you want to know how to put a constructor in a function signature, -XDataKinds is the answer)

Comment: "`S` and `Z` are not types, but just type constructors producing the type `Nat`" should be data constructor producing data of type `Nat`

Comment: @Jules, it is clear that with DataKinds `S` and `Z` become types as well.
But what are the values of these types?

Answer (score 57):

Here is my take:

Consider a length indexed Vector of type:

```
data Vec n a where
  Vnil  :: Vec Zero a
  Vcons :: a -> Vec n a -> Vec (Succ n) a

data Zero
data Succ a
```

Here we have a Kind `Vec :: * -> * -> *`. Since you can represent a zero length Vector of Int by:

```
Vect Zero Int
```

You can also declare meaningless types say:

```
Vect Bool Int
```

This means we can have untyped functional programming at the type level. Hence we get rid of such ambiguity by introducing data kinds and can have such a kind:

```
Vec :: Nat -> * -> *
```

So now our `Vec` gets a DataKind named `Nat` which we can declare as:

```
datakind Nat = Zero | Succ Nat
```

By introducing a new data kind, no one can declare a meaningless type since `Vec` now has a more constrained kind signature.

Comment: _untyped functional programming at the type level_ is a great observation.

Comment: This is exactly what Simon Peyton Jones says in one of his lecture. See https://youtu.be/brE_dyedGm0?list=TLPQMTMwNTIwMjGbmPzQCvHwyQ&t=3092