# Type restriction in type declaration

Tags: haskell, type-systems, gadt, data-kinds, phantom-types

There is famous example of the type level natural numbers:

```
data Zero
data Succ n
```

I have a question about desirable restriction when we applying type constructor `Succ`. For example, if we want to make such restriction in function definition, we can use the class and context, like in this code:

```
class Nat n where
  toInt :: n -> Int
instance Nat Zero where
  toInt _ = 0
instance (Nat n) => Nat (Succ n) where
  toInt _ = 1 + toInt (undefined :: n)
```

It's impossible to use `toInt (undefined :: Succ Int)`, it's ok.

But how to realize similar restrictions on type level constructions (perhaps with some advanced type extensions)?

For instance, I'd like to permit using of type constructor `Succ` only with type `Zero` and with something, like this: `Succ (Succ Zero)`, `Succ (Succ (Succ Zero))` and so on.
How to avoid such bad example on compile time:

```
type Test = Succ Int
```

(for now, there is no compilation error)

P.S.: It is more interesting for me how to create a restriction on the type declaration of the last sample

Comment: See [What is the DataKinds extension of Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20558648/what-is-the-datakinds-extension-of-haskell) for precisely this example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nowadays, we use the `DataKinds` extension:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, KindSignatures, ScopedTypeVariables #-}

-- N is a type, but is also a kind now
-- Zero, Succ Zero, ... are values, but are also type-level values of
-- kind N
data N = Zero | Succ N

-- (We could import Proxy the library, instead)
data Proxy (n :: N) = Proxy

-- Now n is restricted to kind N
class Nat (n :: N) where
  toInt :: proxy n -> Int

instance Nat Zero where
  toInt _ = 0
instance (Nat n) => Nat (Succ n) where
  toInt _ = 1 + toInt (undefined :: Proxy n)
```

We can then use `toInt (Proxy :: Proxy (Succ Zero))`. Instead, `toInt (Proxy :: Proxy (Succ Int))` will raise a kind error, as wanted.

Personally, I would also replace proxies with more modern stuff like `AllowAmbiguousTypes` and `TypeApplications` so to remove the unused argument.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, KindSignatures, ScopedTypeVariables,
             AllowAmbiguousTypes, TypeApplications #-}

data N = Zero | Succ N

-- Now n is restricted to kind N
class Nat (n :: N) where
  toInt :: Int

instance Nat Zero where
  toInt = 0
instance (Nat n) => Nat (Succ n) where
  toInt = 1 + toInt @n
```

Use this as `toInt @(Succ Zero)`. The `toInt @n` syntax chooses the `n` in the typeclass. It does not correspond to any value exchanged at runtime, only a type-level argument which exists at compile time.

---

Using

```
type Foo = Succ Int
```

also errors out as wanted:

```
    • Expected kind ‘N’, but ‘Int’ has kind ‘*’
    • In the first argument of ‘Succ’, namely ‘Int’
      In the type ‘Succ Int’
      In the type declaration for ‘Foo’
```

Comment: thanks; just noticed another one: `Proxy` in `class Nat (n :: N) where
  toInt :: proxy n -> Int`...

Comment: @WillNess No, that's actually a standard idiom (which I don't like, but I conform to). Using the type variable `proxy` instead of the type `Proxy` allows for other proxy types as well. It is often used in [libraries](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Proxy.html#v:asProxyTypeOf)

Comment: @chi, I am confused, but your first example is not compilable. The second one is wrong: firstly you slightly changed condition. `Succ` is not value constructor as you written, but must be a type constructor. And real error of 2st example is `>:3:12: error:
    Not in scope: type constructor or class 'Succ'`
    `A data constructor of that name is in scope; did you mean DataKinds?`

Comment: I mean for 2nd sample: `Main> type Foo = Succ Int`

`<interactive>:3:12: error:`
`Not in scope: type constructor or class 'Succ'`
`A data constructor of that name is in scope; did you mean DataKinds?`

Comment: @Vladimir You did not copy all my code in a Haskell, including the line which enables `DataKinds`

Comment: I've copypasted 1st your sample and have got:  C:\_TMP\Haskell\tmp>ghci ans1.hs
GHCi, version 8.6.5:
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( ans1.hs, interpreted )

ans1.hs:18:37: error:
    * Expected a type, but `n' has kind `N'
    * In an expression type signature: n
      In the first argument of `toInt', namely `(undefined :: n)'
      In the second argument of `(+)', namely `toInt (undefined :: n)'
   |
18 |   toInt _ = 1 + toInt (undefined :: n)
   |                                     ^
Failed, no modules loaded.

Comment: Second example works as you described if I've put `type Foo = Succ Int` in code file (not in ghci as I did before). But role of `Succ` in your code is not clear for me yet :(

Comment: @Vladimir I indeed forgot `(undefined :: Proxy n)` in my first snippet, sorry. It should be fixed now. About `Succ`: it plays the same role as in your question. `Succ Int` is an error, since `Succ` wants a number in `N`, and not a type -- this is what you wanted, right? So you can only use `Succ Zero, Succ (Succ Zero), ...`.

Comment: In my code (conditions, if you want) `Succ` is type constructor, but in your code `Succ` looks like data (value) constructor. It confuses me... Perhaps, it is  a form of `DataKinds` magic?

Comment: @Vladimir Yes, that's `DataKinds` in action. With that extension, term-level constructors like `Zero, Succ` in my code get "lifted" at the type level. So you can use them as usual in values, but you can also use them in types. The notation `class Nat (n : N)` indicates that `Nat` is not a class of types (we can't use `Nat Bool`) but a class of `N` (we can use `Nat Zero`), so it refers to the lifted values. So we have `Int, Maybe Int, [Int] :: *` as plain types, and `Zero, Succ Zero, ... :: N` as "numbers at the type level". Here `*` and `N` are called "kinds" (a sort of "type of a type").