# Precise definitions of promotion and lifting

Tags: types, terminology

In the literature on typed functional programming, these terms appear frequently, and their definitions seems to be assumed. I don't seem to be able to find it spelled out formally anywhere.

The first term is *promotion*. This applies when, for example, creating a little metalanguage. Here (in Haskell) the `Integer` type is promoted into the `Expr` type, enabling `Expr` to represent integers:

`data Expr = EInt Integer`

That's clear enough, and I can understand how it is similar to the promotion of a `char` to an `int` in C. The integer values are essentially unchanged, but they're wearing a new uniform, so to speak.

It's very clear to me that the term *lifting* applies, for example, in the case of functors. The whole substance of Haskell's `Functor` typeclass is the ability to lift a function into the functor with `fmap`.

The problem is that the terms are also used to refer to more complex transformations, e.g. ["With -XDataKinds, GHC automatically promotes every suitable datatype to be a kind, and its (value) constructors to be type constructors."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20558648/what-is-the-datakinds-extension-of-haskell)

This promotion from data constructors into type constructors makes something less powerful and fancy into something more powerful: it makes data constructors into type constructors etc.

The term *lifting* can apparently be used in the same way: ["GADTs cannot be promoted, because the type equalities in their definition cannot be lifted to kind equalities."](https://repository.brynmawr.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1014&context=compsci_pubs).

I'm probably just being pedantic, but I can't see how the basic meanings of the two terms and the fancy type-level meanings are really the same thing, except in a sort of loose sense. So I'm looking for clarification, and ideally a pithy definition of the terms *promotion* and *lifting* that makes it clear when it's safe to use them, and just how precise or vague they are.

Comment: I'm not sure about promotion, but I think all uses of lifting can be seen as mapping a function from one category to another, even if the source and target categories are the same (as in the case of all Haskell `Functor`s, which are endofunctors for the category **Hask**) or when the categories are only sort of implied (e.g. the Kleisli categories where functions of type `a -> m b` exist as arrows between types `a` and `b`.) *Lift*, then, just refers moving from a "lower" (source) category to a "higher" (target) category.

Comment: I see, I should have guessed that category theory would be involved. I see that Riehl's book talks about promoting "any equivalence to an adjoint equivalence", which sounds definitely like something different.